# Firebase CLI always shows Error: Invalid project id: \

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Every time I use a firebase command this error occurs:

```
...\WEBRTCTest\FirebaseRTC> firebase use --add

Error: Invalid project id: \.
```

```
\WEBRTCTest\FirebaseRTC> firebase use --clear

Error: Invalid project id: \.
```

The error occured after I accidently run the command:

```
firebase use \
```

Prior to that all was working fine.

I tried to reinstall firebase-tools using npm and also re-cloning the example project from github.
Also tried to logout using `firebase logout` but it gives me the same error:

```
\WEBRTCTest\FirebaseRTC> firebase use --clear

Error: Invalid project id: \.
```

I´m thankful for any idea as i´m stuck right now.

Answer (score 14):

It seems Firebase CLI can get into a bad state if you accidentally `use` an invalid project name, then all commands will fail, even `firebase use --clear` (I'm using version 8.2.0)

This happens even if there is no `.firebaserc` file.

I got it to work by finding a valid project name in my Firebase Console on console.firebase.google.com and then run the firebase command `use --clear` but overriding the active project with the `--project` parameter indicating a valid project name, like this:

```
$ firebase use --clear --project="myvalidprojectname"
Cleared active project.

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

Then subsequent commands will run smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really worked for me and I had to use the project ID as shown in the project settings on Firebase.

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of hassle.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered explicitly telling firebase what project to use?

```sh
# get list of projects
$ firebase projects:list

# add project id to most firebase CLI commands 
$ firebase <my command> --project=<my project ID>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it did not work. I got the same error trying both commands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it works now. But I found a work-around: It´s working again after cloning the project in a new folder.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I believe this is an issue with the firebase command. No need to copy and paste though, just rename the folder to something else and it works!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the "default" in `.firebaserc`, then it works:

From:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "default": "YOUR DEFAULT PROJECT ID"
    }
}
```

TO my project id "pwa-proj"

```
{
    "projects": {
        "default": "pwa-proj"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.

Answer (score 1):

i had to delete the `.firebaserc` file ( to the all commands work again

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI keeps information about the current project in a (hidden) file called `.firebaserc`. It looks like your `.firebaserc` file got corrupted, so you might want to delete the file and then run `firebase use` or `firebase add` again .

Answer (score 0):

I came a cross this problem and realized that there was another firebase.js file in the same folder as my project folder. When I deleted that firebase file, boom! it worked. Just check to see that there is no other firebase.js file that could be read from apart from the one you intend to be read from.